# WCF WebService client in vb.net or c# code

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, wcf, client

I am trying to create a .Net console application consuming a WCF WebService without needing an app.config file.
Therefore I should "translate" the following XML of the app.config into c# or vb.net code.
Could anyone help me:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="CustomBinding_ILogMateReceiver">
                <binaryMessageEncoding />
                <httpTransport />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:57222/LogMateReceiver.svc/binary"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_ILogMateReceiver"
            contract="MisWcfWsLogMate.ILogMateReceiver" name="CustomBinding_ILogMateReceiver">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: because I want to share the exe with other people in the company and I don't also want to give them the config file - easier to handle for them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'll begin by saying that the reason you are getting down voted is because this question shows no research effort; however, since it is an interesting question I decided to entertain it.

This will probably get you 90% of the way there; however, the one thing I did not figure out is how to express the custom binding properly. I made an educated guess and given the information thats about as far as I can get. I leave the rest to you.

```
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();
binding.Elements.Add( new HttpTransportBindingElement());
binding.Elements.Add(new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement());
var ep = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:57222/LogMateReceiver.svc/binary");
var factory = new ChannelFactory<MisWcfWsLogMate.ILogMateReceiver>(binding, ep);
var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
channel.MyMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Aelphaeis, for your help - I can better accept being downvoted by you offering a solution then not having a solution and my problem was solved :-)